# Equatable Tuple for testing in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm testing a series of functions in Swift.

I need to compare a complex tuple type (and this should be in a single `XCTAssertEqual` statement rather than comparing all of the constituent types of the tuple.

For simplicity I try to compare my known answer to itself in this minimum example:

```
let answer: (question: [String], correctAnswerIndex: [String], givenAnswers: [String], givenAnswerIndex: [String]) = (question:[], correctAnswerIndex: ["0"], givenAnswers: ["0"], givenAnswerIndex: ["0"])
XCTAssertEqual(answer,answer)
```

Predictably this results in the error that the typle types are not Equatable

> Global function 'XCTAssertEqual(*:*:_:file:line:)' requires that
>   '(question: [String], correctAnswerIndex: [String], givenAnswers:
>   [String], givenAnswerIndex: [String])' conform to 'Equatable'

I would therefore want a separate extension in testing to make these equatable, the closest answer I can see involve generic parameters and really I want to make this as simple as possible...

Comment: Why don't you simply do it as `XCTAssert(actualAnswer == expectedAnswer)` ?

Comment: Because they aren't equatable, so the Swift compiler delivers the same error message.

Comment: Have you really tried? Tuples cannot be Equatable, but you can apply `==` for compatible tuples.

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns Are you sure a struct isn't more appropriate than a tuple for this?

Comment: The suggestion by @OOPer is correct. Just use `XCTAssert(actualAnswer == expectedAnswer)`.

Comment: The real problem (this is a minimum viable subset) does not have equatable types.

Comment: Then please try to describe your real problem. As you see, current description is less than minimum.

Comment: Tuples do not lend themselves to equatability. You have designed your app incorrectly for testing and you have misused tuples. You should rethink what you’re doing.

Comment: @matt can you justify this? You don't know the design of the App, so I'm interested in how you know this. How do you know so much with no evidence?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `Equatable`, there is a work-around, which is writing a `==` function for your `Answer` tuple:

```
typealias Answer = (question: [String], correctAnswerIndex: [String], givenAnswers: [String], givenAnswerIndex: [String])
func ==(answer: Answer, anotherAnswer: Answer) -> Bool {
    // Implement your own equation logic here!
    return answer.question == anotherAnswer.question
        && answer.correctAnswerIndex == anotherAnswer.correctAnswerIndex
    && answer.givenAnswers == anotherAnswer.givenAnswers
    && answer.givenAnswerIndex == anotherAnswer.givenAnswerIndex
}

let answer: Answer = (question:[], correctAnswerIndex: ["0"], givenAnswers: ["0"], givenAnswerIndex: ["0"])
XCTAssertTrue(answer == answer)
```

Comment: There is no need to implement this `==` function. You can compare tuples with `==` without the need to implement `==`.